# oh my zsh permissions error with MAMP

Tags: php, mamp, oh-my-zsh

I ran into an issue with MAMP 4 using PHP 5.6.27 or 7.0.12 and WP CLI 0.25.0 using 5.6.25 by default. According to the [WP CLI docs](https://wp-cli.org/docs/installing/#using-a-custom-php-binary), to use MAMP’s version of PHP, I should prepend my `$PATH` with:

```
PHP_VERSION=ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | tail -1
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/${PHP_VERSION}/bin:$PATH
```

I’m using Oh My ZSH and when I add that to my `.zshrc` file, I have:

```
export PATH="~/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
# Homebrew
export PATH=/usr/local/Homebrew/:$PATH
# Use MAMP's version of PHP.
PHP_VERSION=ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | tail -1
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/${PHP_VERSION}/bin:$PATH
```

Now, when I run `source .zshrc` or open a new terminal window to  use the new configuration, I get an error `/Users/USERNAME/.zshrc:60: permission denied: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/`.

I’ve tried modifying the MAMP directory with `chown` and that doesn’t seem to be the issue. My `.zshrc` file in the home directory is symlinking to a dot files directory elsewhere, but I tried placing it directly in `~/` without success.

Any ideas why I might be getting that permissions error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PHP_VERSION=ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | tail -1`

should be

`PHP_VERSION=$(ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | tail -1)`